# C# How do I read from the top of a richTextBox?

Tags: c#, text, scroll, richtextbox

Currently my richtextbox displays all the information that I want but it automatically scrolls all the way down.

How do I allow a user to see the text from the top of the richtextbox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: windows forms, asp.net, wpf, silverlight, other? where in .NET are we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this answer may help

[Prevent Autoscrolling in RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626988/prevent-autoscrolling-in-c-richtextbox)

Comment: Not really working for me. Is there like an alternative? Thanks.