# how to prevent delayed wheel scrolling in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

When you scroll using the mouse wheel inside a RichTextBox the scrolling continues for a little while after you stop turning the wheel.
I want it to stop as soon as the wheel stops turning instead.
What's the way to go to implement this behaviour?

It doesn't look like there is any related property on the control.

I plan on using it as a Console-like read-only output, so it has nothing fancy attached so far: just a black-background Form-Wide box.

--SOLUTION--
Overriding `WndProc()`'s `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` case neatly did the trick,
as was pointed out in the comments below.

Just be sure to use bitshift to test the IntPtr sign

Comment: System feature: `Settings->Devices->Mouse->Choose how many lines...`

Comment: @Jimi are you suggesting to change the mousewheel setting system wide or..?

Comment: If you really want to change that, you could suppress the predefined behavior by handling the scroll yourself. E.g., see [How to scroll a RichTextBox control to a given point regardless of caret position](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65222953/7444103), [Synchronize the Scroll position of two Controls with different content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67907473/7444103)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100569/disabling-smooth-scrolling-on-richtextbox

Comment: This "feature" is sometimes called *inertia*.

Comment: Hans' link points to the question. The accepted answer on that thread is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11104336/5438626. I just tried it myself. It's simple, elegant and it works.