# Best practice for multi-color textbox in WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a tool in C# using WinForms. - It's reading and modifying .txt files, and I would like to incorporate one of the basic functionalities we see in IDE's: Color coding.

The .txt files I'm working on has a few keywords and phrases that would be very useful to color in order for the user to easily read the content.

So far I've found a post about using RichTextBox and defining one selection at the time which you then give a different color. This just seems super inefficient to me when I want to keep evaluating and coloring the content, and for some reason part of me is telling me that this is ugly code.

```
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font("Verdana", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

I was originally hoping for a way to encode the text in a way (like html) in order to color specific parts of it before feeding it to the textbox, which then renders it correctly in an editable field. But it seems this isn't really an option.

What is the best practice for doing stuff like this? Multi color coded editable text fields. Am I missing something? Is there a "pretty" way to do this?

I hope what I'm asking makes sense, I've not done alot of UI programming. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would go to the User Experience (UX) SO site, they are crazy good when it comes to this stuff.

Comment: `Is there a "pretty" way to do this?` - yes, it's called [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You are describing the exact purpose for the RichTextBox control, and yet you want to avoid using it.  Odd.  See [How to append text to RichTextBox without scrolling and losing selection?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550415/719186) to solve the flicker issue when highlighting the selected text.

Comment: I didn't say that I wouldn't use it - I said that I didn't understand how to use it efficiently for my specific purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing now is not as efficient as it will be when you modify the RTF text and set it using richTextBox1.Rtf = yourModifiedTextString;

Steps to achieve this:

1. Read your text from file in strFileText variable
2. Set that text to the richTextBox using `richTextBox1.Text = strFileText;`
3. Read the rich text (rtf text) thus generated using `string strRichText = richTextBox1.Rtf;`
4. Replace the keywords in your text with the rich text format of your colour `strRichText = strRichText.Replace("int", "\cf2 int \cf1"); // to show int in second colour in colour table and then set the colour for next text back to default colour (colour 1)`
5. Set the Rtf text as `richTextBox1.Rtf = strRichText;`

I hope this will give you an idea for what you asked for.

For more details about how to add fonts and colours to your RTF, you can read

- [RTF Basic (Simple Tutorial)](http://www.pindari.com/rtf1.html)
- [RTF v1.5 Specifications (detailed)](http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm)
- [RTF v1.6 Specifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140277%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for something like this