# Syntax Highlighting performance issue

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, richtextbox, syntax-highlighting

I have a RichTextBox and once the user loads a file, my program proceeds to scan the entire file in order to change the color of certain words. Here is my code:

```
static Regex cKeyWords = new Regex(@"\b(?=[a-gilr-w])(?:
     s(?:hort|i(?:gned|zeof)|t(?:atic|ruct)|witch) | c(?:ase|har|on(?:st|tinue)) |
     e(?:lse|num|xtern) | i(?:f|nt) | f(?:loat|or) | d(?:o|efault|ouble) | un(?:ion|signed) |
     re(?:gister|turn) | vo(?:id|latile) | while | break | long | typedef | auto | goto
     )\b",
     RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

...

programTextBox.Enabled = false;
int selectStart = this.programTextBox.SelectionStart;
programTextBox.SuspendLayout();
MatchCollection matches = cKeyWords.Matches(programTextBox.Text);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    if (match.Index == 0)
        programTextBox.Select(match.Index, match.Length/* - 1*/);
    else
        programTextBox.Select(match.Index + 1, match.Length - 1);
    programTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
}
programTextBox.Select(selectStart, 0);
programTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
programTextBox.Enabled = true;
programTextBox.ResumeLayout();
```

Problem: my code takes about 5 and a half seconds to scan and change the colors of all the keywords in a file that has 200,000 characters.

I've been told before that I shouldn't use a Regex for that kind of stuff, but after doing several tests I figured out that the: `MatchCollection matches = cKeyWords.Matches(programTextBox.Text);`

only takes about 0.1s and removing the

```
programTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
```

reduces the total execution time of my code from 5.5s to about 0.3s

How? Why? And most importantly: What can I do?

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention that. Yes, it is.

Comment: RichTextBox is not particularly efficient.. You could try applying the syntax highlighting by building the RTF yourself: [rtf spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=10725). Assign the result to the [`Rtf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.rtf.aspx) property of the textbox.

Comment: Suspend painting before the loop and resume it immediately after it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282384/richtextbox-syntax-highlighting-in-real-time-disabling-the-repaint or better find a control which supports syntax highlighting. There are several open source libraries available.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe batching your work between calls to `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` might help.

Comment: Actually, I'm already doing this. Check the edited post and sorry for forgetting it!

Comment: @DrewNoakes `SuspendLayout` and `ResumeLayout` makes no sense in richtextbox. It is helpful only in container controls.

Comment: See [How to append text to RichTextBox without scrolling and losing selection?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550415/719186).

Comment: @LarsTech I took a quick look at the link you posted and it seems to be about screen flickering when updating the richtextbox. However, my problem is not screen flickering (because there isn't): it's about the time it takes to apply the changes to the text.

Comment: @OC_ By suspending the drawing to make your highlight changes, you are saving a lot cycles. Try it.

Comment: Suspend layout and after u've done changes Resume like @SriramSakthivel suggested and  then call RichTextbox.Refresh().  
This will paint only visible items. I did it for my datagridview project, saves a lot of time.

Comment: I actually tried adding Suspend() and Resume() (Drawing/Painting) as extension methods for my RichTextBox, called them and also added Refresh() after Suspend(), but it doesn't seem to work any faster...

Answer (score 1):

I maintain the C++ syntax highlighter for VS Code, which has [single regex patterns](https://github.com/jeff-hykin/cpp-textmate-grammar/blob/6f039d2bccfd6822edeb112deb0d88e9eceefcdf/syntaxes/cpp.tmLanguage.json#L4677) that are more than 9000 character's long. The regex you wrote is very efficient, probably too efficient (removing the lookahead would help more than breaking up the words).

This is a fundamental UI issue. The UI is slow, there is no way for something like VS Code to highlight 200,000 lines in under a second. And that's fine because the user is never going to be looking at 200,000 lines at one time. So instead Atom/VS Code intelligently only call the equivalent `programTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;` for the lines that are visible. Same with Sublime and other text editors; they only update what-you-see and what-was-changed, because it is very expensive to mess with the GUI.

Instead of updating the UI ~100,000 times, do what Sriram Sakthivel's comment says (not sure why he didn't make his an answer) "Suspend painting before the loop and resume it immediately after it. [RichTextBox syntax highlighting in real time--Disabling the repaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282384/richtextbox-syntax-highlighting-in-real-time-disabling-the-repaint) or better yet find a control which supports syntax highlighting. There are several open source libraries available."

This is effectively the same solution that is used for every text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487661/how-do-i-suspend-painting-for-a-control-and-its-children)?

This blocks painting and actually seems to block it properly. I only had a small test file to put through it, but it seemed to work pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing syntax highlighting yourself, try using [ICSharpCode.TextEditor](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30936/Using-ICSharpCode-TextEditor), the syntax-highlighting editor for the SharpDevelop IDE.

Comment: please post answer and then references.