# Change RichTextBox highlight BackColor and ForeColor

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm making a syntax analizer, so what I do is to change the colors and fonts of some words in a RichTextBox, but sometimes, when the text is too long, my richtextbox shows some highlighting. I want to change these to the same BackColor and ForeColor as the current word properties, so user can't notice this highlighting. How can I change the RichTextBox highlighted word Back and Fore colors ?

Comment: See [How to append text to RichTextBox without scrolling and losing selection?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6550415/719186)

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks! That's what I was asking for :))
Working fine :P

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change color and back color of selected text, try this
(If I understood your question correctly)

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
this.richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set all of the text in the `richtextbox` then type

```
this.richtextbox.SelectAll();
```

And then follow up with

```
this.richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
this.richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
```

As Reza Aghaei said.

If you want it do this automatically then double click the richtextbox to create the text changed event and put the code inside this.

```
 private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      //Remember the cursor position & length
      int SelectionStart = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
      int SelectionLength = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;

      //Select all text and change color
      richtextbox1.SelectAll();
      richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
      richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;

      //Select original text
      richTextBox1.Select(SelectionStart, SelectionLength);
 }
```